# How to define Map objects in Open API 3.0, for GET API

Tags: java, yaml, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

I have GET API, which takes Map as a request param. How to define this in Open API 3.0, in yaml format

```
@GetMapping
public void getDevicesInfo(@RequestParam(required = false) Map parameters)
{

}
```

Open API is not supporting Map type.

Comment: Do you mean what Java annotations to use (i.e. if you generate the API definition from the source code) or what's the OpenAPI YAML syntax for dictionaries/maps?

Comment: Can you provide an example of such request?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your `YAML` file you need to add `additionalProperties` for `Map` in Java and use `parameters` for `@RequestParam` as :

```
/api/v1/test:
  get:
    tags:
      - test
    operationId: getDevicesInfo
    parameters:
      - name: parameters
        in: query
        required: false
        schema:
          type: object
          additionalProperties:
            type: object
    responses:
      '200':
        description: OK
```

The generated GET API looks like:

[image]

I hope it helps you :)

Comment: Can one generate a Map<String, Map<String, Object>> type?